# Asp.Net Core 3.1 EmailSender is not working in server side after deploying

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

> I am using Asp.Net Core 3.1,And I am using default **IEmailSender**
>   interface provided from Microsoft send email, unfortunately it is
>   not working in server side after deploying

In my code, I **tried to send the Email through localhost machine** and it is **working and sending the email perfectly** then I **deployed the system**, but, when I need to **send email through the application hosted in the server**, sending email **is not working**, I mean the **code is working and updating the information**, but, the **email not arriving**.

This is the sample of **EmailSender** **class** that inherit from **IEmailSender** **interface**:

```
public EmailSender(string host, int port, bool enableSSL, string userName, string password)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.enableSSL = enableSSL;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
            EnableSsl = enableSSL
        };

        // To avoid any error come from domain email server
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

        client.SendMailAsync(
                new MailMessage(userName, email, subject, htmlMessage) { IsBodyHtml = true, Priority = MailPriority.High }
            );

        //client.Send(
        //    new MailMessage(userName, email, subject, htmlMessage) { IsBodyHtml = true }
        //    );
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

> How can I allow sending email through the server, knowing that I checked the security in server end test sending email through the telnet and it is working fine.

Comment: You could try making the method async and `await`ing the call to `SendMainAsync`. Your request is probably ending before the task can run because what you are doing is a "fire-and-forget". Also, do you have any exception handling and logging?

Comment: Thank you @Crowcoder, I will try to put the `async` and `await` ing the call, and also I will put the log to check what is happening

Comment: @Crowcoder I added both `async` and `await` + `ILogger` but it is sending the email normally with no error in logs and the Email not arrived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft **"System.Net.Mail"** namespace is **obsolete** and they mentioned that you can use **"MailKit" library instead**.

You can read more from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1

> After updating EmailSender to **"MailKit"**, send email is working fine
> and also more reliable in fact of the time.